# Create an SQL temp table using EXEC

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a temp table dynamically since I don't know in advance all the columns I will use.

So let's say I need to create a table with fixed columns

```
Item int, start int, end int
```

and

variable columns `(Rcpt1 int, Rcpt2 int)` that I managed to put in an nvarchar variable `@columnsRcpt` + 2 more variable columns `@Start` and `@End`.
So I try to build my query as such :

```
@qry = 'CREATE TABLE #InvRcpt (SKU nvarchar(25), '
        + @Start + ' int' 
        + @columnsRcpt +', 
          Vendu int, 
          [Retrait d''inventaire] int, 
          Ajout int, 
          Solde int, ' 
          + @End + ' int)'
Exec(@qry)
select * from #InvRcpt
```

But it doesn't work, I'm sure that I miss something syntax wise.

Comment: 'Then' is not part of the code (it's part of the text).
Is there a way I can create a temp table using exec then use the table outside of the exec? I need to fill the table once it's created then to update it after some data processing

Comment: You need to put the select inside the dynamic SQL too. The #temp table created in dynamic SQL is created in its own, separate context, and no longer exists once the exec() is done.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Is there another way for doing what I'm trying to do? Let's say instead of creating a temp table '#InvRcpt' I create a table 'dbo.InvRcpt', what would be the string to put in '@qry'? Will my string be valid if I change table name? + I will need to fill the table from another exec

Comment: A table that's globally visible (whether temporary or not) will avoid the problem you're talking about, but you'll encounter a more serious problem as soon as two users try to execute your sproc at the same time. @d_anass, can you perhaps give a little more detail as to the larger problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The problem is that I need to make a report from a table that contains multiple receipts for items and another table that contains the inventory value for those items per day.
Every item should be represented in one line, there should be a column with the inventory quantity at the first day of the given period, a column with the inventory quantity at the last day of that period, and columns for every reception we did for that item during this period that should be named (reception1, reception2, ...).

Comment: The way I intend to do it is : 
1- select distinct receptions in a temp table : one column will be id (incremented automatically), one column the reception number and a third column that will be the word "reception"+ID
2- create another temp table with all the needed columns (now that I know all the columns)
3- Populate the table and start updating it for every reception.

I'm not sure this is the best way of doing it, but this his how I imagined the solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One thing you can do, if you want to access the temporary table to access outside the dynamic query by modifying it inside the dynamic query is to declare it outside the dynamic query. Say

```
CREATE TABLE #InvRcpt (SKU nvarchar(25))
declare @qry nvarchar(500)
set @qry = 'alter TABLE #InvRcpt add '
    + @Start + ' int,' 
    + @columnsRcpt +', 
      Vendu int, 
      [Retrait d''inventaire] int, 
      Ajout int, 
      Solde int, ' 
      + @End + ' int'
Exec(@qry)
select * from #InvRcpt
```

Then you should get the output and also use the temp table outside.

Comment: @TabAlleman, that's what I thought too, but I tried this and it actually worked (once I removed the superfluous `table` keyword).

Comment: Actually it worked. I used a select after (outside) the exec and I had all the columns. Thank you all

Comment: Removed the extra table word, was a typo :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your environment uses the semi-colon (;) as command terminator, try the following

```
@qry = 'CREATE TABLE #InvRcpt (SKU nvarchar(25), '
        + @Start + ' int' + @columnsRcpt +', Vendu int, [Retrait d''inventaire] int
        , Ajout int, Solde int, ' + @End + ' int)'
        + ';' 
        + 'select * from #InvRcpt;'

Exec(@qry)
```

As indicated by the previous comment by Sean Lange, you would need to invoke the SELECT statement in the same batch with the CREATE to be able to get the results.

Comment: `Exec` command makes temp procedure from `@qry` and executes it. When that procedure ends, all temp tables created in it will be dropped immediately, so you can't gain access to the created table from outside current dynamic query. You can use **global temp table** `##InvRcpt` to keep it alive, but do not forget to **generate names for it dynamically** (if two users call your function, global table created by first user will be visible for all and second user would not create table with the same name).

Answer (score 2):

CREATE the #InvRcpt outside of EXEC (@qry) by trying the following:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##InvRcpt1') IS NULL
BEGIN
EXEC ('CREATE TABLE #InvRcpt1 (SKU nvarchar(25), ' + @Start + ' int' + @columnsRcpt + ', 
          Vendu int, 
          [Retrait d''inventaire] int, 
          Ajout int, 
          Solde int, ' + @End + ' int)')

END

SELECT *
INTO #InvRcpt
FROM ##InvRcpt1

SELECT *
FROM #InvRcpt
```

Answer (score 0):

Since #TmpTable is only used within the immediate query, you have to use a global temp table (##TmpTable) when you try to create a table by executing a created SQL statement.  Also, in order for the Sql editor to allow you to use ##TmpTable, you will also need to create a useless instance of this and then drop the table before use. I agree that building the table one column at a time is a better approach, but doing making a table this way is certainly possible.  Remember that you will have to also use EXEC statements to add data to the tables as any reference to the fields will cause errors while compiling. Good luck!

---

declare
@DelTable varchar(100) = 'drop table ##TmpTable',
@SqlStr varchar(1000) = ''

--Useless code to create a table so you don't get an error when you reference the ##TmpTable later in the code

create table ##TmpTable (a varchar(1))
exec (@DelTable) --runs drop table ##TmpTable

-- build your create table string dynamically here, I'm setting it as static for demo purpose 

set @SqlStr = 'create table ##TmpTable([A] varchar(10), [B] varchar(10), [C] varchar(10))'

exec (@SqlStr)